# Operator + overload for c++ in class

Tags: c++, oop

This is for assignment in my faculty, I want to do overload for `operator +` to matrix I create new matrix an put the sum in this matrix and I print it but it print nothing so can anyone help me to solve this problem?

```
class matrix
{
private:
  int* data;
  int row, col;

public:
  matrix();
  matrix(int r, int c, int num[]);
  friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, matrix mat1);
  friend istream& operator >> (istream& in, matrix& mat);
  int getrow();
  int getcol();
  int getdata(int i);
  int setrow(int r);
  int setcol(int c);
  int setdata(int num[]);
  matrix operator+ (const matrix& mat2);
};
```

Now I write this code an it prints nothing can anyone help me to solve this?
first I make setter and getter for the data.

```
matrix::matrix(){
  row=0;
  col=0;
}

matrix::matrix(int r, int c, int num[])
{
  row = r;
  col = c;
  data = new int[r*c];
  for(int i=0; i < (r*c); i++)
    data[i] = num[i];
}

matrix::getrow() { return row; }
matrix::getcol() { return col; }

matrix::setrow(int r) { row=r; }
matrix::setcol(int c) { col=c; }

matrix matrix::operator+ (const matrix& mat2)
{
  matrix mat3;
  for(int i=0; i < mat3.getrow() * mat3.getcol(); i++) {
    mat3.data[i] = data[i] + mat2.data[i];
  }
  return mat3;
}
```

---

```
int main(){
  int num2 [] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8};
  int num3 [] = {1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1};

  matrix x;

  matrix mat2(3, 3, num2);
  matrix mat3(3, 3, num3);
  matrix mat4;
  mat4 = mat2 + mat3;
  cou << mat4;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `mat3` is default constructed. What are the dimensions of a default constructred `matrix` ?

Comment: You should spend some time on a readable layout. Don't lean on the Enter key, and let a decent text editor take care of the indentation for you.

Comment: they must have told you about the rule of 0/3/5 otherwise this assignment is pointless

Comment: @user463035818 zeros

Comment: It prints nothing but you didn't show us the code to do printing...

Answer (score 1):

You did not set the dimensions of `mat3`, so `getrow()` and `getcol()` both return `0`, and the buffer is too small to contain the data you put it in, so you also suffer from buffer overflow.

Add a private constructor that only accepts the dimensions without initializing values.

Your next problem is that you don't have a copy/move constructor/operator=(), so the assignment into `mat3` in `main()` is not well defined.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some suggestions

#### 1. Initialization mistake

try to add a constructor overload method like this:

```
matrix::matrix(int r, int c)
{
    row = r;
    col = c;
    data = new int[r*c];
    for (int i = 0; i < r*c; i++) {
        data[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

then in `operator+` overloading function, initiate mat3 by using this method:

```
matrix mat3(mat2.getrow(), mat2.getcol());
```

#### 2.overload `=` operator is essential since you decide to `mat4 =`

```
matrix matrix::operator= (const matrix& from_mat)
{
    matrix to_mat(from_mat.getrow(), from_mat.getcol());
    for (int i = 0; i < from_mat.getrow() * from_mat.getcol(); i++) {
        to_mat.data[i] = from_mat.data[i];
    }
    return to_mat;
}
```

#### 3. in `main` function, just use `matrix mat4 = mat2 + mat3;`

Answer (score 0):

There are many things wrong with your post. Others have pointed a few things out, here is a more complete list IMO:

- You are asking about a display issue, but your title is about `operator+`, and you do not provide the implementation of `ostream& operator<< ( ostream&, matrix& )`. There is also no reason why displaying the contents of a matrix should modify it, so it should be `ostream& operator<< ( ostream&, const matrix& )` (this will also eliminate the need for the pass-by-value variant).
- Some of your constructors allocate memory, but you did not define a destructor (`~matrix()`) to handle deallocation, and have no copy constructor (`matrix( const matrix& )`). Read about destructors and memory management.
- You overload the default constructor `matrix()` but it is currently not possible to update the size or contents of your matrix. What is the point of a default constructor if the empty matrix it creates cannot be changed later on? You should also define `data = nullptr` in this case.
- The role of the setters for number of rows and columns (`setrow, setcol`) is unclear; setting the size attributes should affect the memory allocation (i.e. `data`), but currently it does not. You also declare those methods as returning `int`s, but do not return anything. You should delete both of these methods; there is no need for them, and your implementation is currently wrong.
- In `operator+` the first thing to check is that the input has the same size as the current matrix. The second thing is to allocate the output correctly (with `matrix( row, col )`), which implies the need for an additional constructor `matrix(int r, int c)` (as suggested by the other answers). The third is to declare this method as constant `matrix operator+ ( const matrix& other ) const`.
- There is a typo in your main, `cou` should be `std::cout`.
- Finally, what happens if I write `matrix x( -1, -5, NULL );`?